# How can I remove the preview display from drop section using Angular Drag and Drop?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, display

I am using the Drag and Drop functionality of Angular in order to drag a card from a card list to a empty div.

[image: Pizza list]

I have been checking the API documentation of Angular's drag and drop and I have found possible configuration on the preview of the drag but not the drop (the biggest image in the example)

Origin:

```
<mat-accordion
      cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['viewer0', 'viewer1', 'viewer2', 'viewer3']"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
    >
      <div *ngFor="let serie of seriesList">
        <div
          cdkDrag
          [cdkDragData]="serie"
        >
..........
```

Display div:

```
    <div cdkDropListGroup>
      <div
        cdkDropList
        cdkDropListConnectedTo="series-list"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
      >
..........
```

Expected: The preview of the image must be NOT displayed in the right section at the moment that we are dragging the card.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I just found the native class **.drop-preview** on the documentation and I just made some changes in the scss file:

```
.drop-preview {
  background: $accent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  p {
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: Nice pizza]

Answer (score 1):

my friend, the best way to do this is with the CSS Classes, where you can change what you want for example the preview.

```
.cdk-drag-preview {
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
 }
```

All this are in that link:
[link](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)

Answer (score 0):

```
.cdk-drag-placeholder {

  opacity: 0;
}
```